# Display Product Attribute Value only if db value exists - Magento

Tags: magento-1, product-attribute

I want the following to display only if there is a value for this field in the database:

```
<p>Available Colors: <?php  echo $_additional["color_spec"]["value"]; ?></p>
```

What I had attempted does not work:

```
<?php if ($color_spec = $_product->getcolor_spec());
if (trim($color_spec)) {
    echo 'Men / Women: ' . $this->htmlEscape($color_spec);
}
```

Comment: if that attribute have yes then only display right

Comment: yes, that is what I'm needing to do.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If it's yes or no attribute use this

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('freeshipping')=='Yes') { ?>
    <li><?php echo "Free Shipping"; ?></li>
<?php } else { ?>
    <li><?php echo "No Free Shipping"; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
```

if it's text box use this

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('emi');
$attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
if ($attribute_value) {
    echo "EMI Start With: " ."Rs.". $attribute_value;
}
```

Comment: the first use would not work because it needs to show what's in the db for that value.  The second one still shows: Available Colors: No.  If there are no available colors in the db for that item, I do not want it to echo anything at all.